# data not save in database in admin django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

in model.py create a class in which 3 fields are there

```
class signUp(models.Model):
username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
email = models.EmailField()
password = models.IntegerField()
```

in serializer.py

```
class SignupSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
class Meta:
    model = signUp
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

def create(self, validated_data):
    email = validated_data['email'],
    name = validated_data['name'],
    password = validated_data['password']

    return signUp.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

in views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def signup(request):
    if 'username' not in request.data:
        response = {'message': 'please enter username'}
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    elif 'email' not in request.data:
        response = {'message': 'please enter email'}
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    elif 'password' not in request.data:
        response = {'message': 'please enter password'}
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        signup = signUp.objects.all()
        serializer = SignupSerializer(signup, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = SignupSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.validated_data.get('username')
            message = f'successfully signup {user}'
            return Response({message: message}, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

All functions work and signup is a success, but after that data not show up in the database. How do I save it in the database?

Comment: You need to add the [**`@api_view`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view)  decorator to the view

Comment: but it not give the html form to post

Comment: Sorry, I dont get you

Comment: when i post the data its give  "detail": "Unsupported media type \"text/plain\" in request."

Comment: and when i send only username and email it not give message for password instead of that it give error  "detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 7 column 1 (char 62)"

Comment: It seems you are not sending the data as *JSON*. Why so?

Comment: why its give this ...."detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Comment: i am sending the {
    "username" : "abhishek",
    "email" : "john@doe.com",
    "password" : "secretpass"
}

Comment: @Avinash you're sending the password in `CharField` format and your model uses `IntegerField` field.